# Pandas column1 values, column2 names, is there a way to group and rearrange the data so that column2 becomes row header

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Data is an unique value, id is repeated multiple times in an excel file. Data is column 1 and id's are column 2. I would like to group the unique data values to an id without losing any. Then set the column index as the id, and paste the data values associated below. Then do the same thing with the second id and paste that id's values below 1 cell to the left of the first id column. Could anyone help me sort it out to such layout?

[image]

Comment: Consider include your data as text, not picture!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have varying length columns in a dataframe. So `NaN`s are unavoidable.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[2,3,3,4,2,1,3,4], 'col2':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3]})

# First problem
df2 = df.pivot(columns='col2')["col1"]
df2 = df2.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values))
print(df2)

# Second problem
def concat(s):
  return s.tolist()

df3 = df.groupby('col2').agg(concat)["col1"].apply(pd.Series)
print(df3)
```